# Unknown cipher in list: TLSv1

Tags: magento-connect

I'm trying to `All4coding Offline Maintenance Page` using Magento Connect Manager ver. 1.9.2.4 and I'm getting this error: `Unknown cipher in list: TLSv1`

I found some solutions on here already, however it looks like either my Magento is broken, or they removed the line of code that everyone is talking about..

```
$this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');
```

I'm using Hostgator Shared hosting to host the website, if that makes a difference.
Does anyone have a solution for this, or what should I try to do?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php` and change:

```
$this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');
```

to:

```
$this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1);
```

Comment: `$this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');` isn't in the file

Comment: Yes, it has been remove on the 1.9.2.3. Sorry, but I've not a solution. I am looking, too

Comment: The latest solution is upgrading to Magento 2.